# Set Nullable property default value to Nothing not working as desired

Tags: vb.net, nullable, short-circuiting

I have a property which type is `Nullable` of `Integer` an default value `Nothing` as shown below:

```
Property TestId As Integer? = Nothing
```

the following code evaluates the property TestId to Nothing (as wanted)

```
Dim test As RadTreeNode = rtvDefinitionCreate.FindNodeByValue(DefinitionHeaderEnum.Test)
If test Is Nothing Then
    definition.TestId = Nothing
Else
    definition.TestId = test.Nodes(0).Value
End If
```

but the code below evaluates as 0 (default value for `Integer`, even when is `Integer?` with default value `Nothing`)

```
Dim test As RadTreeNode = rtvDefinitionCreate.FindNodeByValue(DefinitionHeaderEnum.Test)
definition.TestId = If(IsNothing(test), Nothing, test.Nodes(0).Value)
```

What is wrong with the above code? Any Help??

(later in the code when call the property, the property has 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It' because you are compiling you code with `Option Strict Off`.

If you would compile your code with `Option Strict On`, the compiler would give you an error, telling you that it can't convert from `String` to `Integer?`, avoiding such suprises at runtime.

---

This is a weirdness when using `properties`/`ternary operator`/`option strict off` in VB.NET.

Consider the following code:

```
Class Test
    Property NullableProperty As Integer? = Nothing
    Public NullableField As Integer? = Nothing
End Class

Sub Main()
    ' Setting the Property directly will lest the ternary operator evaluate to zero
    Dim b = New Test() With {.NullableProperty = If(True, Nothing, "123")}
    b.NullableProperty = If(True, Nothing, "123")

    ' Setting the Property with reflection or setting a local variable 
    ' or a public field lets the ternary operator evaluate to Nothing
    Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "123")
    Dim implicitLocal = If(True, Nothing, "123")
    b.NullableField = If(True, Nothing, "123")
    b.GetType().GetMethod("set_NullableProperty").Invoke(b, New Object() {If(True, Nothing, "123")})
    b.GetType().GetProperty("NullableProperty").SetValue(b, If(True, Nothing, "123"), Nothing)
End Sub
```

---

Another difference to consider:

```
Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "123")
```

will evaluate to `Nothing` but

```
Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(SomeNonConstantCondition, Nothing, "123")
```

will evaluate to `0`

---

You can create an extension method to do the nasty work for you.

```
<Extension()>
Function TakeAs(Of T, R)(obj As T, selector As Func(Of T, R)) As R
    If obj Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Return selector(obj)
End Function
```

and call it like

```
definition.TestId = test.TakeAs(Of Int32?)(Function(o) o.Nodes(0).Value)
```

Comment: I think `Option Strict On` does not help here since the If operator does an automatic widening conversion from Nothing to 0 (type of `test.Nodes(0).Value`) - but the solution should work!

Comment: @PaulB. `Option Strict On` would help here in the way that will cause a compile error, highlighting the problem.

Comment: For me `Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, 1)` does not cause a compile error but converts Nothing to 0 and then 0 to a nullable 0.

Comment: @PaulB. Yes, that's true. The arguments of your ternary operator are `Nothing` and `1`. `1` is an integer, and `Nothing` can converted to an integer also (`0`), so the compiler is happy and knows the ternary operator will return an integer. But try `Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "SomeString")`. The compiler will raise an error when `Option Strict On`.

Comment: Also, with `Option Strict Off`, there's a difference in `Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "abc")`, in which case `i` will be `Nothing`, and `SomeClass.NullableIntProperty = If(True, Nothing, "abc")`, in which case `NullableIntProperty` will be `0`.

Comment: Agreed. But assuming reguapo's `test.Nodes(0).Value` is of type `Integer` his code will (and probably does) compile with `Option Strict On` and display the behavior he described.

Comment: @PaulB. Also agreed. But given the class names in the code reguapo is using telerik's ASP.NET controls, where the `Value` property of `RadTreeNode ` is a [string](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radtreenode_value.html) :-)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I am lacking that telerik background :)

Comment: @PaulB. I have updated my answer to show some more VB weirdness :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys, but i have another quick question based on what @BigYellowCactus mention above, why `SomeClass.NullableIntProperty = If(True, Nothing, "abc")` will be 0 and `Dim i As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "abc")` will be `Nothing` or why `Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "123")` will evaluate to Nothing but `Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(SomeNonConstantCondition, Nothing, "123")`
wil evaluate to 0

Comment: When using `Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(True, Nothing, "123")`, the compiler knows that the expression can only return `Nothing`, so it will return `Nothing`. But when using `Dim localNullable As Integer? = If(SomeNonConstantCondition, Nothing, "123")`, it might be returning the false-part of the expression. So the compiler has to find a common type between the two arguments. The compiler will choose `Integer`, since `Nothing` can be converted to an integer (will result in `0`)...

Comment: ..., and a string can also converted to an integer (calling `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger()`), but not to `Integer?`.

Comment: I was trying to use `definition.TestId = If(IsNothing(test), new Integer?, test.Nodes(0).Value)` but now i am receiving an `InvalidCastException` when evaluates the second argument `test.Nodes(0).Value` (**Specified cast is not valid**), because of what @BigYellowCactus comment above, an string can be converted to `Integer` but not to `Integer?`, any work around??

Comment: What's the value of `test.Nodes(0).Value` in this case?

Comment: the value in this case is "32" (but could be any `Integer` as `String`)

Comment: well i did `definition.TestId = If(IsNothing(test), new Integer?, CType(test.Nodes(0).Value,Integer))` and it works but have to write to much code, any elegant solution?

Comment: That is the way to go. But you also write an extension method to handle the cast. See my updated answer.